# how to send data from servlet to Jsp using request dispatcher

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

servlet:

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
            System.out.println("Received Value: " + request.getRequestURL());
            response.getWriter().append("Decoded string: ").append(
                    Utils.getDataFromFeedbackLink(request.getPathInfo().substring(1, request.getPathInfo().length())));

            String decodeValue = Utils
                    .getDataFromFeedbackLink(request.getPathInfo().substring(1, request.getPathInfo().length()));

            request.setAttribute("finalData", decodeValue);

            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(decodeValue);
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
```

jsp:

```
<body>
    Hello World ::::
    <%=request.getAttribute("finalData")%>
</body>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SubmitFeedbackServlet</servlet-name>

    <description></description>
    <servlet-class>com.techjini.tfs.servlets.SubmitFeedbackServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SubmitFeedbackServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/submitfeedback/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

i am getting value but when i try to send value from Servlet to Jsp then  each time same servlet loaded so am unable to get value inside jsp please suggest me how to get value from servlet to jsp using request dispatcher or some thing i did wrong please point me where am doing mistake .

Answer (score 1):

If you store some data in request attribute in will be seen on forwarded page. Just set req.setAttribute("key", "value") and it will be visible on destination page via ${"key"}

Answer (score 0):

in the line "RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(decodeValue);" 
the decodeValue should contain the name of the jsp file . can you check that by printing the value of decodeValue  on console.